# Jekyll - About Page adds slash to URL and breaks site

Tags: jekyll

I copy-and-pasted my index.html and called the new file about.html. The content is exactly identical. However once I navigate to about.html via the url `http://localhost:4000/about` it automatically adds the slash and changes it to `http://localhost:4000/about/`, which it doesn't do with other pages. For some reason the about page then also doesn't seem to be able to load any of the css or image files correctly, and any links in the menu lead to `http://localhost:4000/about/art` as opposed to `http://localhost:4000/art`.

The pages exist, too... `http://localhost:4000/about/art` leads to the art.html page, but again unable to load any assets.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide an example on how do you load assets? And how do you generate links in files?

Answer (score 0):

1. One way to overcome problems with relative links is to define routes and pages in
   `_config.yml` file. For example for "about" page you could have:

```yaml
about_page: "/about"
```

and then in other source files you can generate links to the page with:

```html
<a href="{{ site.about_page }}">About</a>
```

2. Another solution would be to set permalinks in page files, for example:

```yaml
---
permalink: /about/
---
```

and then build urls with

```html
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

3. To make sure that assets are loaded correctly on all pages you can preprend assets url in layout file, like:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/style.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```